# How do I find commit hash of a file using GitLab API?

Tags: git, api, hash, gitlab, git-commit

I am trying to find out what the commit hash is for files within my repository. Different files got modified with different commits.

I see this information displayed on GitLab web interface:
[image: File's commit hash vs master's commit hash]

But how do I get this information using the GitLab API? I tried doing:

```
GET /projects/:id/repository/files
```

https://gitlab_server/api/v3/projects/1234/repository/files?file_path=test/file2.tconf&ref=master

But the commit_id from the response matches HEAD's hash **0f05a8e4bf45942b1189fce923184129821845f1**, instead of what's seen in the screenshot above.

```
{
  "file_name": "file2.tconf",
  "file_path": "test/file2.tconf",
  "size"     : 44,
  "encoding" : "base64",
  "content"  : "...",
  "ref"      : "master",
  "blob_id"  : "50450759d2b0694b044ed3d7eaf93c2c98dacbba",
  "commit_id": "0f05a8e4bf45942b1189fce923184129821845f1"
}
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

*last-commit-id* now exists and gives just what you asked for: the last commit that modified that specific file.

see [GitLab's *get-file-from-repository* API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/repository_files.html#get-file-from-repository)

Answer (score 0):

*get-a-single-commit* I've just tested it myself for my project, used it to get information about the last commit, I guess that you can now easily get what you want.

see [GitLab's get-a-single-commit](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/commits.html#get-a-single-commit)

GET /projects/:id/repository/commits/:sha

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/5/repository/commits/master"
```